# Run Spark app in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, web

is there any tutorial where showing how to deploy Spark project in tomcat? the official Spark docs are very limited and I can't find any solution for that in the web.
thanks

Comment: Anything in [these](https://github.com/simonrice/SparkServletExample#spark-servlet-example) [documents](http://www.sparkjava.com/readme.html#title17) help?

Comment: @summea yeap, very simple, but very informative example. thank u, dude!

Comment: dead link in the comment...